# Typescript and Docker Slow Compilation

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I recently updated to Docker 2.2.0.0 and am compiling a Typescript (3.7.5) `NestJs` project.

The typescript compilation takes a long time (a few minutes) when run in docker, but only take a few seconds run locally.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "diagnostics": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Application hangs on:

```
Starting compilation in watch mode.
```

Then after several minutes it completes the build and the server starts.

Update:

- Command to compile / run: `nest start --watch` which uses `tsc` to compile the application in watch mode.
- My docker file is below:

```
FROM OUR-custom-docker-image

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production=false

EXPOSE 4200
CMD yarn db:migrate && yarn start:dev
```

Edit:
- I ran `` both locally and within docker to see the runtime difference:

locally

```
Files:                       1270
Lines:                     140094
Nodes:                     516055
Identifiers:               186330
Symbols:                   775100
Types:                     255282
Memory used:              618234K
Assignability cache size:  284236
Identity cache size:          603
Subtype cache size:          1045
I/O Read time:              0.21s
Parse time:                 0.72s
Program time:               2.25s
Bind time:                  0.52s
Check time:                 7.32s
transformTime time:         0.15s
commentTime time:           0.00s
printTime time:             0.64s
Emit time:                  0.65s
Source Map time:            0.01s
I/O Write time:             0.12s
Total time:                10.74s
```

docker

```
 Files:                       1269
 Lines:                     140047
 Nodes:                     515825
 Identifiers:               186267
 Symbols:                   775022
 Types:                     255265
 Memory used:              618717K
 Assignability cache size:  284236
 Identity cache size:          603
 Subtype cache size:          1045
 I/O Read time:              1.13s
 Parse time:                 1.01s
 Program time:               5.88s
 Bind time:                  0.74s
 Check time:                 8.87s
 transformTime time:         0.21s
 commentTime time:           0.00s
 printTime time:             1.75s
 Emit time:                  1.76s
 Source Map time:            0.03s
 I/O Write time:             1.11s
 Total time:                17.25s
```

Comment: What’s the command you’re running to build this; is it in a Dockerfile or elsewhere?  What host OS?  Can you provide enough source code to be a [mcve]?

Comment: Added a few more details. Host OS is Windows 10. Just converted to Docker 2.2 today, and this issue started (no other changes)

Comment: No I can't create a minimal reproducible example. It is a very large and complex application. I am just wondering if there are any obvious ways to optimize compilation performance.

Comment: You converted to Docker 2.2 from what?  Not using Docker at all or a previous version?

Comment: Previous version. Didn't record the previous version prior to upgrading unfortunately. But 2.2 introduced a new UI, and changed the local file access system and permission system. So wondering if it is some file read/write issue. Haven't been able to find any similar problems with recent dates though.

Comment: Ran `tsc` with `extendedDiagnostic` both locally and within docker.

Comment: When you look at the ts server log file, is a lot of time being spent on `DirectoryWatcher:: Added::` lines?

Comment: @coler-j did you manage to solve the issue ?

Comment: I just rolled back to an older version of docker (pre 2.2)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known problem](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4515) that accessing NTFS files from WSL2 is very slow. When you run `tsc` from within a Docker container, it is running under WSL2, and `tsc` needs to access the files on NTFS, hence you are encountering the cross-file system slow down issue.

You can confirm the file access slow-down with a quick experiment. Have a git repository stored on NTFS. Run `git status` natively in Windows and compare the run time when `git status` is run from a docker container. You will notice a dramatic slow down because of the cross-file system access.

On my machine I see the following results using Powershell:

```
# Run git status from Windows
Measure-Command -Expression {git status} | select -Property TotalSeconds

TotalSeconds
------------
   0.1172657

# Run git status from Docker
Measure-Command -Expression{ docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v ${pwd}:/git alpine/git status} | select -Property TotalSeconds

TotalSeconds
------------
  25.4326815
```

Just to confirm that the additional time is not taken by starting the git container, the following compares the time to run `git version`:

```
# Run git version from Windows
Measure-Command -Expression {git version} | select -Property TotalSeconds

TotalSeconds
------------
   0.0821073

# Run git version from Docker
Measure-Command -Expression{ docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v ${pwd}:/git alpine/git version} | select -Property TotalSeconds

TotalSeconds
------------
   1.2742293
```

The startup time of the docker container takes less than 2 seconds, while the difference in time to perform that `git status` which needs to traverse the repository files is around `25 seconds`.

If you really need to use the node installation from within a Docker container,  you can avoid the cross-file access problem by storing your git repository directly in the WSL2 file system. That way, the file access is WSL2 to WSL2 (assuming you enable WSL2 support in Docker Desktop), which is fast.